# Volume velocity to gain web audio

Tags: javascript, audio, midi, web-audio-api

I'm trying to set a velocity value, a value that is in a midi signal to gain. The velocity ranges from 0 to 127.

The documentation on the [web audio api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) albeit well done, doesn't really say anything about this.

At the moment I've this to play sounds :

```
  play(key, startTime) {    
    this.audioContext.decodeAudioData(this.soundContainer[key], (buffer) => {
      let source = this.audioContext.createBufferSource(); 
      source.buffer = buffer;                   
      source.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
      source.start(startTime);
     });
  }
```

I didn't find anything to use the velocity values that range from 0 to 127. However I found [gain node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode) that applies a gain.

So my function is now this:

```
  play(key:string, startTime, velocity) {    
    this.audioContext.decodeAudioData(this.soundContainer[key], (buffer) => {
      let source = this.audioContext.createBufferSource(); 
      source.buffer = buffer;                   
      source.connect(this.gainNode);
      this.gainNode.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
      this.gainNode.gain.value = velocity;
      source.start(startTime);
     });
  }
```

Eehhh... if I apply the midi velocity value to the gain, I obviously have a sound that is insanely loud. So I'd like to know either of those two questions:

- Can I somehow use the velocity value directly ?
- How can I convert the velocity value to gain ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MIDI specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/the-midi-1-0-specification) says:

> Interpretation of the Velocity byte is left up to the receiving instrument. Generally, the larger the numeric value of the message, the stronger the velocity-controlled effect. If velocity is applied to volume (output level) for instance, then higher Velocity values will generate louder notes. A value of 64 (40H) would correspond to a mezzo-forte note […] Preferably, application of velocity to volume should be an exponential function.

The General MIDI specifications are not any more concrete.

The [DLS Level 1 specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/dls-level-1-specification) says:

> The MIDI Note Velocity value is converted to attenuation in dB by the Concave Transform according to the following formula:
>
> *atten<sub>dB</sub>* = 20 × log<sub>10</sub>(127<sup>2</sup> / *Velocity*<sup>2</sup>)
>
> and fed to control either the volume or envelope generator peak level.

You then have to map this attenuation to the gain factor, i.e., `gain = velocity² / 127²`.

And many hardware synthesizers allow to select different curves to map the velocity to volume.

Comment: Thanks I tried this. The result was quiet aweful, it may be because I might have misunderstood what you meant by "you then have to map this attenuation to the gain factor".  Anyway, by trying out different formulas myself I've found one that I find good enough in the dynamics it provide (gain = velocity² / 6400). It might not be scientifically accurate but with your formula I had 8 db gain for a 80 velocity 20*log(16129/6400) = 8. That is yet way too load. I'll accept the answer since it seems correct, but that's not what I'll use I guess.

Comment: To map dB to a linear factor (if that is what a gain node uses), drop the 20*logarithm, and note that attenuation is the opposite of gain. So the gain factor would be `velocity² / 127²`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is correct, because I don't know that much about sound but this seem to work:

this.gainNode.gain.value = velocity / 100 ;

So a velocity of 127 = a gain of 1.27

Ultimately I think what is better is dividing 1 in 127 values and each of those correspond to their respective midi value. However code is easier this way so yeah, it works.